# Choosing the right IBM MobileFirst version for implementation

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

There are multiple versions of IBM mobilefirst platform available. What are the different decision points that need to be considered for choosing a particular IBM mobilefirst version for implementation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are only two versions that should be considered at this time: 7.1 and 8.0, and the only reason to choose 7.1 is if you've already invested in a version older than 7.1.  The reason I say that is because V8.0 is rearchitected in a number of significant ways that make it more suitable for Cloud deployments and Open development models.  Therefore, the cost to migrate from an older version to V8 is somewhat greater than to migrate to 7.1, and 7.1 will continue to support all the latest mobile operating systems.  V8 on the other hand has many new features that 7.1 will never have (as you'd expect)  If you're looking to play with the technology, go download the free DevKit from https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/.

So bottom line: If this is a new deployment/purchase/etc. then I'd always suggest V8 as the preferred choice.  However if you already have an investment in older versions, V8 is still the preferred choice, but migration to V8 may take more time than to migrate to 7.1.

Does that answer your question?

Comment: Yes. Thanks for the clarification. That helps.

Answer (score 1):

Mobilefirst 7 or 7.1 will be most reliable as of now since it has been in the market for some time and most of the pmr's would already be resolved. Within 7 and 7.1 itself there are few changes like 7 has desktop browser environment which is not present in 7.1. So you would want to check out the differences before chosing 7 or 7.1. But personally I would recommend you to go for mfp8 since there are lots of new features added into it. It might be a bit unstable but eventually everyone would upgrade to 8 is what I feel.